# Prestashop Database Exception

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop

I have a flash module that calculates the measurements of the product, once calculated to give the button to add to cart see this error:

> [PrestaShopDatabaseException]
>
> Duplicate entry '739-6261-21011-0' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
UPDATE `ps_cart_product`
        SET `id_address_delivery` = (
            SELECT `id_address_delivery` FROM `ps_cart`
            WHERE `id_cart` = 739 AND `id_shop` = 1
        )
        WHERE `id_cart` = 739
```

> At line 765 in file classes/db/Db.php

```
760. WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
761.        }
762.        elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS'))
763.        {
764.            if ($sql)
765.                throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
766. 
767.            throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
768.        }
769.    }
770.
```

> DbCore->displayError - [line 418 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]

```
413.            if ($this->connect())
414.                $this->result = $this->_query($sql);
415.        }
416. 
417.        if (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_)
418.            $this->displayError($sql);
419. 
420.        return $this->result;
421.    }
422. 
423.    /**
```

> DbCore->query - [line 578 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]

```
 573.   public function execute($sql, $use_cache = true)
 574.   {
 575.       if ($sql instanceof DbQuery)
 576.           $sql = $sql->build();
 577. 
 578.       $this->result = $this->query($sql);
 579.       if ($use_cache && $this->is_cache_enabled)
 580.           Cache::getInstance()->deleteQuery($sql);
 581. 
 582.       return (bool)$this->result;
 583.   }
```

> DbCore->execute - [line 3774 - classes/Cart.php] - [1 Arguments]

```
 3769.      '.(Configuration::get('PS_ALLOW_MULTISHIPPING') ? ' AND `id_shop` = '.(int)$this->id_shop : '');
 3770. 
 3771.      $cache_id = 'Cart::setNoMultishipping'.(int)$this->id.'-'.(int)$this->id_shop.((isset($this->id_address_delivery) && $this->id_address_delivery) ? '-'.(int)$this->id_address_delivery : '');
 3772.      if (!Cache::isStored($cache_id))
 3773.      {
 3774.          if ($result = (bool)Db::getInstance()->execute($sql))
 3775.              $emptyCache = true;
 3776.          Cache::store($cache_id, $result);
 3777.      }
 3778. 
 3779.      if (Customization::isFeatureActive())
```

> CartCore->setNoMultishipping - [line 446 - override/controllers/front/OrderOpcController.php]

```
441.                     }
442.                 }
443.             }
444. 
445.             // As the cart is no multishipping, set each delivery address lines with the main delivery address
446.             $this->context->cart->setNoMultishipping();
447. 
448.             $is_old_browser = false;
449.             preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
450.             if (count($matches) < 2) {
451.                 preg_match('/Trident\/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}; rv:([0-9]*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
```

> OrderOpcController->initContent - [line 180 - classes/controller/Controller.php]

```
175. 
176.            if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className)))
177.                $this->initHeader();
178. 
179.            if ($this->viewAccess())
180.                $this->initContent();
181.            else
182.                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Access denied.');
183. 
184.            if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_footer || (isset($this->className) && $this->className)))
185.                $this->initFooter();
```

> ControllerCore->run - [line 373 - classes/Dispatcher.php]

```
368.            // Execute hook dispatcher
369.            if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher))
370.                Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
371. 
372.            // Running controller
373.            $controller->run();
374.        }
375.        catch (PrestaShopException $e)
376.        {
377.            $e->displayMessage();
378.        }
```

> DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 28 - index.php]

```
23. *  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
24. *  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
25. */
26. 
27. require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
28. Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

With payment in five steps prestashop if it works but with the One Page Checkout module does not work and this error appears.

Comment: Witch version of Prestashop is it ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw you accepted a response on Prestashop official forum, I will post it here

> key n ps_cart_product table contains 4 elements:
>   - id_cart
>   - id_product
>   - id_address_delivery
>   - id_product_attribute
>
> in your query you update the key element (id_address_delivery)
>   from your sql update i see that id_address_delivery is equal to: 21011
>   and entry for this id cart and product already exist!

But could you please explain how this helped you ?